# Get data from password protected Excel file using OleDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm using this connection string to access excel(2007,2010) files

```
oleConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR = NO;IMEX = 1;'";
```

this work fine until i try to get data from protected List.
I know the protection password.
So how could i access protected list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971514.aspx) you can provide the credentials with the connection string `User ID=UserX;Password=UserXPassword` but this works for access

But

> I'm afraid. You cannot open a connection to a password-protected
>   spreadsheet unless you have already manually opened the spreadsheet in
>   Excel . The described error is with the
>   Excel ODBC provider, but the behavior is identical in the Jet 4.0 OLE
>   DB provider. Your other option is to remove the password from the
>   spreadsheet, and rely on some other security mechanism (like
>   restricting permissions on the folder where the file resides) to
>   control access.