# How to Read a password protected excel file using OLEDB connection string

Tags: vb.net

I am Developing application Using VB.net.
What I need is read Password protected excel file using OLEDB Connection String.
If any one have solution to resolve this problem please let me know...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get data from password protected Excel file using OleDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870838/get-data-from-password-protected-excel-file-using-oledb)

Comment: Thanks Mr Bummi. I tried By This way to. It throws error "Could not Find Installable ISAM"..

Comment: Sorry Mr Bummi 
I received "External table is not in the expected format".

Comment: objExcel.Workbooks.open(oFolder.path & "\" &  oFile.Name,Password:="YourPassword")                                     you can set the password while opening your file

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook/                                                                 you can try hope this helps

Comment: Thanks For the Rly. But I open the file using OLEDB connection String.
 Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim MyCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
                MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & INF & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR = NO;IMEX = 1;'")
        MyConnection.Open()
        MyCommand.CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]"
you want Me add the Code 
objExcel.Workbooks.open(oFolder.path & "\" & oFile.Name,Password:="YourPassword")"
Above Of the OLEDB Connection String